# Dimensionality of 1D line through a 2D plane

Tags: geometry, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

What is the dimensionality of the 2D plane with a 1D line going perpendicular through it as depicted [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FMJP.png)? Could one come up with a coordinate system that describes the entirety of this space? In general, how is the dimensionality of a shape formally defined in geometry and how does one go about in finding it? Also, how is the embedding of an $N$-dimensional object in a higher dimensional space formally defined?

Comment: An answer would depend on your background: How much math do you know? Did you ever take a topology class (or read a topology textbook)? If you did not, then most answers will be either extremely long or mean very little to you.

Comment: Not much honestly, I am a physics master student and all I know about topology comes from courses about General Relativity where I've learned some basics about manifolds, but not significantly more than that. Still, any answers you could provide to any of these questions would be greatly appreciated.